# I want to update this query after 5 sec

Tags: jquery

I want to update this query after 5 seconds, for refreshing the div

```
function cart_count(){
    $.ajax({
      url : "functions.php",
      method  : "POST",
      data  : {cart_count:1},
      success : function(data){
        $(".badge").html(data);
      }
    })  
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(function(){// your code here } , 5000);`

Comment: if i write like this its not work setInterva function cart_count(){
    $.ajax({
      url : "../../../../functions/functions.php",
      method  : "POST",
      data  : {cart_count:1},
      success : function(data){
        $(".badge").html(data);
      }
    })
  }, 5000);

Comment: for sure the code is working .. its working in @Mayank answer .. but with `setInterval()` your code will work every 5sec  until you use `clearInterval();` to stop it .. with `setTimeout();`  your code will work once after 5sec .. both answers below show that .. depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: thank you very much ....

Answer (score 0):

Use JS `setInterval()` like:

```js
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 5000);  // It will execute the code on every 5 seconds
// Instead of alert("Hello"); put your ajax() code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
(function(){    
 setTimeout(cart_count(), 5000);
 })();
```